# Put ajax response attribute in to a variable for Google Books cover image

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, variables, google-books

I am trying to put a url from an ajax response into a variable in jquery.
I have written the following code:

```
var thumb = $.ajax({
        dataType: 'json',
        url: 'https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=isbn:' + isbn,
        success: function(response){
            return $(response).volumeInfo.imageLinks.thumbnail;
        }}).responseText;
```

It was my understanding from looking at other answers that I must add .responseText at the end, or the code will continue without waiting for the ajax response.
However, thumb variable remains undefined.

I tried implementing the [following solution](https://codepen.io/CarlosTheDwarf/pen/rBLyd) with relevant changes (As I am passing only one ISBN at a time, there shouldn't be an array. The response should contain only one imageLinks.thumbnail url), but I cannot seem to catch the response correctly.

I looked into other answers, especially [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5316697/jquery-return-data-after-ajax-call-success), but I am still not clear about how to reach the ajax response.

Answer (score 1):

$.ajax is asynchronous, meaning the code will execute completely and the success callback will be fired at a later time.

`var thumb` is evaluated immediately.  Do some reading on "[callbacks](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Callback_function)" and "[promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)" to get more familiar with this topic.

A solution to your issue is:

```
function setThumbnail(thumbnail){
    // this will evaluate later, when the ajax returns success
    console.log('thumbnail gotten!');
    var thumb = thumbnail; // do something with in in this function
}
$.ajax({
    dataType: 'json',
    url: 'https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=isbn:' + isbn,
    success: function(response){
        setThumbnail($(response).volumeInfo.imageLinks.thumbnail);
    }
});
// This line will evaluate immediately and carry on
console.log('ajax executed');
```

I threw in some logs for you to help you understand the order of execution here.
I would also note that `$(response)` looks odd to me, without testing it I think it should probably be just `response.volumeInfo...`.
`console.log(response)` in the success callback to make sure you understand what data you are getting back.

Comment: This is great, but I need thumb outside the function. If I can't use var X = $ajax and return thumb from the function, how can I use it outside the function?

Comment: Do whatever you need to do with the thumbnail info inside of the setThumbnail function.